# Do I need to physically mail in my passport for UK visa?

Tags: uk, us-citizens, standard-visitor-visas, applications, denial-of-entry

I’m trying to apply for a UK visa and I have a few questions...my trip is for May 15th and I don’t want to spend thousands on applying for an expidited visa. Any help would be great, thx!

Comment: If you "have a few questions", it might be a good idea for you to tell us what they are. The Stack Exchange model is based on providing focused answers to specific questions, so requests for "any help" (where it isn't clear what you want help with) are likely to be closed without any answers. Try to include details of your situation - what type of visa are you applying for, where are you applying from, and what is your citizenship?

Comment: I’m American and wanting to apply for a tourist visa bc I was denied entry 7 years ago. Im just trying to make sure I don’t run into any unexpected problems when I reach customs again. I’ve applied online and I have a meeting on Friday for the application picture and finger prints. I thought i found somewhere that I could pay a little extra to not have to physically mail in my passport. If I do have to then I won’t have enough time to apply for a visa before my trip. It she normally takes 15 business days to come up with a decision, sometimes longer if you have been denied entry previously.

Comment: You can’t get a UK visa without mailing in your passport. You may as well forget it.

Comment: Suggest removing the bit of "few questions."  You have a clear single question in the title.

Answer (score 1):

You have to mail your passport within 5 days of your appointment for the standard service or pay extra to fast track. There’s no guarantee you will receive the decision within the published timeframes, whichever option you choose, and in fact UKVI advises against paying the extra fee if you have an adverse immigration history.

https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/usa-apply-for-a-uk-visa/apply-for-a-uk-visa-in-the-usa